# Which is the most secure place of storing database password in a Dropwizard project using Java with Hibernate?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, passwords

We are using Dropwizard as our Java Framework and Hibernate as ORM for Mysql DB. We are storing password of the database user in a configuration file. So, far everything was working fine.

However, recently we faced an issue where one of developer from another team(who have access to our codebase), used our DB username and password to login and delete some data(accidentally).
Neither we can hide our codebase from such teams nor we can remove delete privilege of our database user(due to system requirements).

In such a case, where and how should I store/specify our username and password.

So, far I know of three options and we are going ahead with Option 3-

1- Hibernate's persistence.xml

2- Dropiwizard's configuration.yaml

3- Store password in Dynamic config service and specify its placeholder in our database configuration file.

Any suggestions for better/more secure way?

```
database:
  driverClass: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
  user: <database-user-name>
  password: <password or placeholder here>
```

Comment: Encrypt the password and only store the encrypted version there. `org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` could be extended to utilise something like `jasypt` to decrypt the password

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
However, we are not using Spring in our project.
Though I got the point. Will try to search for similar libraries.

Comment: @ShashankSingh, running into this myself now; did you come up with a solution you're happy with?